# Block submit until some ajax action completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, blocking

Is it possible in JS to block some action until some ajax call returns "ok". 
`somecall` is ajax call.

some simple pseucode:

```
<form>
  <button type="submit" name="hey" onstart="doSomeCall(); while (1) { if (isCallDone()) {break;} }" > </input>
</form>
```

In reality it's not a button, but something similar.

**EDIT1**:

I change pseudocode to explain the situation better. So I need possibilty to block this component in onstart. Is it possible in JS ? In `onstart` runs javascript code.

```
<form>
   <p:tree>
  <p:ajax event="select" onclick="doSomeCall(); while (1) { if (isCallDone()) {break;} }" /> 
   </p:tree>
</form>
```

Comment: You declared a ``let`` for a function that is called once? Shove it in the ``if`` statement. ``if (isCallDone()) { break; }``.

Comment: Thank you for make pseudo-code better.

Answer (score 0):

You can either return false inside the callback function or prevent the [default from happening](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

Answer (score 0):

If you already use jquery please have a look on [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)
Before you start your lengthy operation remove your button click handler

```
$the_button.off("click");
```

and when ajax is resolved add click back

```
$the_button.click(your_handler_function);
```

Comment: Why do so many interactions with the DOM when you can just prevent submitting from happening?.

Comment: @kbariotis There is nothing wrong to use selector, especially if you use id or already have the element selected and stored in private variable. You don't need any speed in the author situation as we do work here with something which takes time already. Further down, I just throw yet another option, which actually very clear in terms of life time. The developer would place "off" in exactly place where he needs it and return "click" at exactly time it has to be done, basically full control on what's happening;  and finally this is convenient to use inside large amount of code.